# export to excel from sharepoint - complex

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, export-to-excel

There is some code/werbparts on our site that display a lot of data in a grid on our site.  In addition, they have another page with a few charts.

I need a way to create functionality to export this to excel so the user can click a button and save everything.

The chart will actually have to be built in excel, I can't just grab the picture from the website and display it.

Also, the data from the grid will have to be put into a spreadhseet.  I am not as worried about this part.

I have exported to excel before, but it was just basically printing some data which was tab delimited with a certain doc type .

This actually will need to use different work sheets and use some excel functionality.

(I need a better answer than use excel services)
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you wish to automate Excel from SharePoint without using its Excel services, which were designed to do exactly that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Excel services are not used for creating excel documents, it is used to access parts of excel documents and display them on the site.  For instance, you can have an excel graph and display it on the site so that excel users could update graphs on the website without having to code.  You can also update cells using excel services, but it isn't that efficient.  I ended up using openXML to create my document.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that Excel services are not very well defined or understood by a lot of people and Microsoft doesn't really help with the definition much.  It took me a lot of research to prove to my manager that excel services were not used for creation of Excel files.

Comment: “Excel Services is a service application that enables you to load, calculate, and display Microsoft Excel workbooks on Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010.” - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546696.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [Epplu](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)s is a  third party library for creating and manipulating excel files(xlsx)

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about sharepoint, but the OpenXML SDK might be what you're after:-
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx